# is there a limit of list items displayed on mega menus?

Tags: website-design, lists, menu, features, mega-menu

So I've redesigning this web that has a lot of menus (> 100 menus total in my app). Is there a limit of list items displayed on mega menus?

[image]

and what should be the best behavior for "See More" button on mega menu? I've been thinking it should go to list of menus page, but I'm afraid it won't show a lot of menu and other menu isn't discoverable by users.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: What is the reason why they must all be on the mega menu? Do they all have the same important and frequency of usage/visit? Is it possible to have some of them be contextual or show up in secondary or auxiliary navigation?

Comment: They at least visited the menu once in every month.  The homepage lists of menu are menus that they use daily, but it's hard to know if there are any new features added. It's okay not to show up in homepage, I just wanted them to be discoverable despite hundreds of menu being in the app @MichaelLai

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a maximum number, other than the difficulty of use.

There are several solutions:

- Left side bar menu with main categories
- Scrolling window
- Horizontal slider

[image: megamenu]

Personally I would avoid the `See more` button, there are enough dynamic tools to show all items.

<sub>*Example [staples.com](https://www.staples.com/cleaning-supplies/cat_SC1683)*</sub>